# What can I do to make my system more tolerant of power cuts?

Tags: kubuntu, power-management

I have a very light/occasional use computer which recently had boot problems following a power cut, resulting in a day's work fiddling around trying to fix it and eventually needing a re-install.

Are there any settings I can adjust to make (k)ubuntu more tolerant of power cuts? I am thinking of less disk write buffering at the expense of performance, no background cleanup tasks, things like that. My aim would be to be able to cut the power harmlessly if the computer has been sitting showing the desktop but doing "nothing" for 10 mins. (I realise it is not really nothing!)

I can't justify the expense of a UPS in this situation, it is just an old computer displaying the output of a USB microscope.

kubuntu 18.04.

Comment: I guess a read-only root filesystem might be a way to go. However, I haven’t tried it myself yet.

Comment: @Melebius Now you say that... maybe always booting and running off a USB stick and not using the hard disk at all?

Comment: What types of filesystems are you using? With journaling filesystems usually there should not be a problem, unless maybe the power loss occurs during very heavy disk activity.

Comment: Where I used to live, power cuts are quite frequent. In general, they are harmless. They can mess up the system if I was running an update or similar, but most of the times there were recoverable. However, with power cuts came power surges sometimes (quite rare, but happens!) and those much more dangerous to the computer hardware. I know you mention that you don't want a UPS, but I would still recommend it, especially that you mention that your computer is old. You can find a cheap UPS that can do the trick.

Comment: With a sound backup plan in place you should be able to get it up and running in under 2 hours or less.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In theory, if your linux is properly configured you should not have boot problems after a power cut. The worst case is you will have lost data but the OS image and services should not be affected.

However, this only works if you use a journaled filesystem such as Ext3/Ext4, ReiserFS, Btrfs, JFS, XFS etc. The first thing I'd do is check to make sure you're not loading your boot partition as Ext2. Note that Ext2 and Ext3 uses exactly the same on-disk data structure so to migrate from Ext2 to Ext3 all you need to do is change the filesystem driver.

#### Theory, meet reality

However, theory and reality sometimes don't agree. There are a bunch of corner cases that theory don't handle.

Some magnetic hard disks can be damaged if power is abruptly cut off. Normally modern hard disks (after 1990s) are manufactured to avoid this condition but then again in theory they do but in practice theory don't always work.

If you're using SSD then some SSD firmware are known to cause disk corruption in some corner cases when power is abruptly lost. It is rare to see this happen in the PC world but is a not uncommon complaint of expensive Red camera users. In fact Red memory cartridges come with a data recovery service by Red because of this issue - which has not been necessary in the PC world. Then again, if it can happen then it can happen no matter how unlikely.

You can mitigate boot corruption issues by doing one or someof the following:

1. Boot from a solid-state disk. It is far less likely for a solid state disk to be corrupt than a magnetic disk (no fast spinning disk reduces a lot of risk). You don't need to go the expensive route and get an SSD. A thumb drive will do just fine. The additional advantage of booting from a thumb drive is you can clone the drive and keep a backup copy of your boot disk in case anything goes wrong.
2. Boot from a read-only disk. If you have a CD or DVD drive you can burn your OS on a CD/DVD and boot from that. It's hard to damage something you cannot write to.
3. Use a Linux distro that doesn't write to disk. There's quite a few distros out there that run completely in RAM and avoid writing to disk. Some were created to make it possible to boot form CD. Some were created for embedded systems that don't have a lot of storage. Because the OS itself don't write to disk it is less likely that stopping the disk will damage the OS. You can still mount your disk and read and write to it for your own data. It's just the OS itself by default will minimize its own disk I/O

Comment: Thank you, I like the idea of always booting off a no-moving-parts USB stick!

Comment: See my answer about data journaling.

Comment: I've ran a linux OS off a USB stick and I found its not a super reliable long term solution. I don't know how many USB drives have good wear-leveling techniques, but the Western Digital usb drive I was using had to be replaced twice over a period of 6 months. Granted, this was 7 years ago, so things may have evolved since them, but nonetheless, I'd be cautious.

Comment: @Drise Have you used the USB stick as a read-only disk in your case?

Comment: I did not. It was a standard boot disk running Ubuntu, treated as if it were a SSD of sorts

Comment: @Drise I've worked with parking ticketing system booting Linux off a thumb drive and it has worked for almost a decade. But this was a system that was carefully configured to write nothing to disk. Log files were logged to ram disk and similarly /tmp was a ram disk. Knowing what I know know we should have forwarded logs to a central server somewhere

Comment: Please keep in mind that their may be crucial differences between usb sticks and ssds.
Usually the controllers in sticks are way worse than the ones in ssds, leading to a significant drop in reliability.
Just make sure you don't take the cheap advertisement you had laying around anyway and if possible, avoid regular writing to it as much as you can.
Mounting your system as read-only would do you a large favor in terms of reliability at power-cuts.

Comment: @B.Tanner You could build your own Live distribution if you were so inclined, that contains the appropriate software/drivers/etc for your uses... that way once you've built it and loaded it onto a USB stick, it never writes to the stick again (no writes = no system screwups). If you want to save images, you can either save to the system's hard drive, or with a bit of clever manipulation, create a persistent second partition on the USB drive after the live image partition.

Answer (score 19):

No. A power cut is what it is.

> resulting in a day's work fiddling around trying to fix it and eventually needing a re-install.

Unless there is an actual hardware related problem (like a broken disk, or fried connectors) this should not have been needed. Without the actual notices you got it is going to be impossible to actually tell you where you went wrong. Sometimes a filesystem check is needed after a loss of power but that is incorporated into the boot process to happen automatically.

> My aim would be to be able to cut the power harmlessly if the computer has been sitting showing the desktop but doing "nothing" for 10 mins.

That is the default: turning off the power of a machine is a hardware thing not software. Only issue you can have is that some things did not get saved to disk but that is no reason for the OS to need to be reinstalled.

I would suggest to take a little risk and cutting the power of that machine and see what happens, and then report the issues you face.

Comment: I second that.  I have been running computers systems at schools across SE Asia.  We have somedays more cuts than power. Never had to reinstall because of this.

Answer (score 8):

Get an "Uninterruptible Power Supply" or "UPS", like [this](https://www.newegg.com/cyberpower-cp1500avrlcd-nema-5-15r/p/N82E16842102048?Description=UPS&cm_re=UPS-_-42-102-048-_-Product&quicklink=true).

This is basically a large battery, you plug your computer into. When a power outage, brownout, blackout or spike happens, the battery takes over and supplies your compute with good quality electricity for (depending how large of a UPS you buy) up to 15 minutes or more. This allows your computer to stay powered during a temporary outage, or give you time to do a proper shutdown.

Some UPS systems even have the ability to trigger an automatic safe shutdown of your computer once they kick in.

Comment: It sounds like you did not read the whole question.

Comment: True but sometimes the answer is correct regardless ;-) A UPS -is- the answer.

Comment: @Rinzwind A UPS is not the answer if it is ruled out on the basis of cost, which is the case here. It's also not the answer when the OP is already aware of the option: repeating it to him doesn't add anything interesting or useful.

Comment: I know but sometimes you need to express to the asker of a question that their idea is wrong. It is a "Teach. Fish. Eat." kinda thing :-) I can rent a UPS for 1 euro a day if needed :D

Comment: A UPS doesn't make a system more tolerant of power cuts, it tries to avoid them.

Comment: True. I once got a call that a server crashed. They had a blackout. Server kept working due to a 100% cool UPS they bought. But the beeping was soooooooooooooo annoying they closed the door to the room where the server was.

Comment: I have a cheap UPS that cost less than 60€ for my NAS. It has USB so the NAS automatically shuts down. OP needed a day to fix the computer. 60€ is less than a days work worth to me.

Comment: Sometimes the right solution isn't the one you want. Doesn't make it not the right solution, though.

Answer (score 5):

Use Ext4 and `rootflags=data=journal` boot parameter.

This [journals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transaction_log) the DATA too (normally only the metadata is journaled, but data can be corrupted).

Enabling this flag makes your write performance slower as data has to be written to disk twice. But it's a good tradeoff.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on your filesystem, but you can use the `sync` flag when mounting (beware, this *will* kill your performance!). Lighter, and actually usable alternative is `dirsync`. Typing `sync` when you know you are going away for a few minutes (thus hibernating the computer is cumbersome) won't hurt, either.

Other options include using `busybox-syslogd` instead of regular syslog (keeps the log in memory), moving `/tmp` and `/var/tmp` to `tmpfs` (if you have enough RAM), moving `/home` to separate partition (and mounting at least `/` with the `sync` flag), disabling disk cache in your browser.

Answer (score 0):

Use following partition scheme (either use GPT or extended msdos partitions):

- `/` 4GiB
- `/boot/` 512MiB
- `/boot/efi/` 512MiB (if needed)
- `/home/` whatever you need, otherwise at least 2GiB
- `/opt/` whatever you need, otherwise at least 1GiB
- `/srv/` whatever you need, otherwise at least 1GiB
- `/tmp/` minimum 2GiB
- `/usr/` minimum 8GiB
- `/usr/local/` minimum 8GiB
- `/var/` minimum 6GiB
- `/var/log/` 1GiB - 2GiB
- `/var/tmp/` minimum 2GiB

All partitions are ext4 filesystems (`/boot/efi/` is vfat) and mounted with *noatime* mount-option.  `/tmp/` and `/var/tmp/` may be mounted with *relatime* mount-option instead. `/boot/efi/` should be mounted with *flush* (vfat) mount-option.

`/`, `/boot/` and `/boot/efi/` should get *fsck* priority `1` in your *fstab*, all other should get `2`.

Use following command to move the ugly `/snap` to where it belongs (it belongs into `/usr/local/`).

```
sudo -i
cd / && mv /snap /usr/local/ && ln -s /usr/local/snap && sync
exit
```

This should give you a robust Linux filesystem. The root-fs `/` will be only round about 100MiB big (without root-homedir `/root/`), easy to backup.

PS a SWAP partition is also always nice to have